# Running tests using the menu vs. shortcut keys

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

In VS2010, if I click on

> Test->Run->All Tests in Solution (CTRL+R,A)

All of my tests will run and I'll be able to see what tests passed and what tests failed.

If I use the shortcut (Ctrl+R,A), then it will break when an exception is thrown.

Why is this experience different?  How can I run all my tests through no matter what without going to the menu bar?

Comment: As per the answer below, CTRL+R, CTRL+A will run tests in debug mode and break on any Exception in the primary test thread. You can also control how Visual Studio handles certain exceptions, ie do not break for AssertException if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chord **"CTRL-R, A"** executes

> Test->Run->All Tests in Solution (CTRL+R,A)

The chord **"CTRL-R, CTRL-A"** executes

> Test->Debug->All Tests in Solution (CTRL+R,CTRL-A)

So the fact is that you *aren't* using the shortcut you *think* you are.